# Excel: How to compare sheets from 2 different workbooks for differences

Tags: vba, excel

I have an original excel file that I have ran a simulation that inputs financial data. I made a copy of this file, and wired the formulas up differently to try and increase calculation performances.

I now have 2 workbooks, the original and the final.  I want to compare each sheet from each of the workbooks together to make sure that the financial numbers have remained the same, to make sure the new formulas are not effecting the numbers received.

I have tried to put copies of the two sheets into one workbook, name them April12 and April15. Then insert a third sheet. In cell A1 of the third sheet, I wanted to use the formula

```
=April12!A1=April15!A1
```

to get TRUE/FALSE values. But the formulas in these sheets reference many other sheets that are not in this new workbook, so all of my numbers turn up as #REF.

Iv googled many different ways of approaching this but I cant seem to get any of them to work. Does anyone know a simple way I can compare just the values from 2 sheets from 2 different workbooks to find out if the numbers have remained the same or have changed?

Note:I am using excel 2010.

Comment: A quick check is sum. And if not too many columns, concatenate them and do a vlookup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you already know how to verify data using formula so is the problem to refer to a row in a different workbook ? if so,  following might be helpful :

```
=[yourFile.xls]SheetName!$Col$Row
```

this way you can update your formula like(yourFile.xls refers to the complete path including the file name) :

```
=[file1.xls]April12!A1=[file2.xls]April15!A1
```